# I have implemented a filter function in angular but it doesn't work

Tags: angular

I have declared a method to filter an array of objects but it's not working. When I make a console.log of the object this.deviceList, it's like this:

```
Array(3)
0:
appConfig: {lastUpdate: "2020-02-03T12:08:02.041Z", config: ""}
tags: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
_id: "5e380d224c8b47002381cbb8"
runsApps: true
state: "ON"
deviceName: "pi3-0000000044499514"
created: "2020-02-03T12:08:02.041Z"
actualVersion: "2.6.4"
isOnline: false
applicationVersion: ""
__proto__: Object
1:
appConfig: {lastUpdate: "2020-02-03T16:50:07.008Z", config: ""}
tags: (2) ["cucu", "trastras"]
_id: "5e384f3f44ccbf00232ec556"
runsApps: true
state: "ON"
deviceName: "holiDevice"
created: "2020-02-03T16:50:07.007Z"
actualVersion: "2.6.4"
isOnline: false
applicationVersion: ""
__proto__: Object
2:
appConfig: {lastUpdate: "2020-01-23T08:29:14.152Z", config: ""}
tags: (2) ["rami", "lele"]
_id: "5e29595a177d86002309478e"
runsApps: true
state: "ON"
deviceName: "lululululul"
created: "2020-01-23T08:29:14.152Z"
actualVersion: "2.6.3"
isOnline: false
applicationVersion: ""
__proto__: Object
```

I don't understand why it's not working. My goal is to obtain the length of this.devicesAlive as the number of devices whose key isOnline is false.  But, it's returning 0 and it should return 3.

My ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProvisionedService } from '../../devices/provisioned-list/provisioned.service';
import { DeviceModel } from '../../devices/device.model';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  deviceList: DeviceModel[];
  devicesAlive: DeviceModel[];


  constructor(private provisionedService: ProvisionedService) {

    this.devicesAlive = [];
    this.deviceList = [];


  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.addDevicesOnline()
    this.provisionedService.getProvisionedDevicesList().then(response => {
      this.deviceList = response;
    })

  }

  addDevicesOnline() {

    this.provisionedService.getProvisionedDevicesList().then(response => {
      this.deviceList = response;

      console.log('deviceList', this.deviceList)

      this.devicesAlive = this.deviceList.filter(elm => {

        elm.isOnline = false
      })
    })
  }


}
```

and my html

```
<mat-card-content>
        <p>
          Thera are {{ deviceList.length }} provisioned devices and {{ devicesAlive.length }} alive devices.
        </p>
        <p *ngIf="deviceList != devicesAlive">
          <mat-icon>error_outline</mat-icon>You have more devices provisioned than devices online
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
```

Could any one help me??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. You don't return anything from the filter callback. 2. Also you have an assignment (`=`) there, not a comparison (`==` or preferably `===`), so you're actually mutating the array content (or would be if they weren't all already false).  Note that this is nothing to do with Angular, so much of the code you've posted isn't relevant to the issue.

Comment: @Tushar please don't encourage people to add off-site examples, the [mcve] should be on site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let deviceList = [{ isOnline: false }, { isOnline: true }, { isOnline: false }];

//let devicesAlive = deviceList.filter(elm => {
//        return elm.isOnline = false
//      });

// You should return the value from an arrow function, either like this or by explicitly calling return elm.isOnline === false.
// And you have assignment "=" instead of "===" in your code. 

let devicesAlive = deviceList.filter(elm => elm.isOnline === false);

console.log(devicesAlive);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Like this** :

```
this.devicesAlive = this.deviceList.filter(elm => {

        elm.isOnline === false

      })
```